# How to get substring of font family using regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring, font-family

I am trying to get the font family from a string representing parts of html. Font-family can be any font, which is why I was thinking of using a regex. String can also be x amount of characters. An example input would be:

```
'<body id="foo" class="bar"><span style="color: #d4d4d4;background-color: #1e1e1e;font-family: Consolas">Example Text</span></body>'
```

The ideal result would be "Consolas". However I'm not that good with regex and not able to come up with an appropriate regex.

*Data comes in as string representation of element*

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to terrymorse(comments) and Gerardo Cabrera(accepted answer)! I was unaware of how to convert html string into an element. Was able to pull out the font-family based on their feedback

Comment: There's a bunch of downvotes just around the corner. Before they arrive, you may append your own attempt.

Comment: Have you considered using the DOM instead of parsing html strings? e.g. `element.style`

Comment: @Evert Unfortunately data comes in as a string representation of the element

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov what would the downvotes be for?

Comment: You can convert the string into DOM elements easily with `let div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = myString;`

Comment: do not consider using regex to parse HTML

Comment: @JustinArias95 : you are normally expected to try something yourself and ask here about the problems you've faced and supply your post with minimal reproducible code sample to demonstrate the issue

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Thanks for the clarification, will keep that in mind for future posts

Comment: @terrymorse Thanks, you're right! I don't know how to mark a comment as the answer so I gave you a shoutout in my question lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like everyone says, it is not a good idea to use regex to try and parse HTML. Just use the DOM like this:

```
// Like the user   terrymorse   did
let div = document.createElement('div'); 
div.innerHTML = '<body id="foo" class="bar"><span style="color: #d4d4d4;background-color: #1e1e1e;font-family: Consolas">Example Text</span></body>';

let children = div.children;

console.log(children[0].style.fontFamily);
```

You could also use split and array functions in order to find the property like this, but the DOM option is way better.

```
var s = '<body id="foo" class="bar"><span style="color: #d4d4d4;background-color: #1e1e1e;font-family: Consolas">Example Text</span></body>';

var x = s.split(";");
var y = x.filter(e => e.includes("font-family"))[0].split('"')[0];
 
var result = y.replace("font-family: ", "");

console.log(result)
```